# Handing regex string to method

Tags: ruby, regex, interpolation

Within a method, I want to dynamically evaluate the following code chunk with a regex:

```
if (/^[A-F][A-Z]*[^\.\*]$/).match(some_value)
```

The method I attempted is this:

```
def check(val)
  if (/^[val][A-Z]*[^\.\*]$/).match(some_value)
    puts "foo"
  else
    puts "waa"
  end
end
check("A-F")
```

The value I am passing in is not making it there correctly. It appears that passing a value in this fashion needs something more. Is this not something you can do with a method?

Comment: It's not necessary to escape `.` or `*` inside `[...]`. `[^.*]` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expected string interpolation. To do that, you need to use the interpolation syntax `#{}`:

```
def check(val)
  if (/^[#{val}][A-Z]*[^\.\*]$/).match(some_value)
    puts "foo"
  else
    puts "waa"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! Dang, that was easy. I did not know you could use the #{} outside of quotes. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, gotcha- gotta click the check.